# Django Error: Profile matching query does not exist

Tags: python, jquery, django, profile

I am working with an Open-Source Social Media Website.
I have a normal Feed.html where Users can see the Post of their Followings.
When I open the feed page it shows this error message.
It never showed an Error Message before.

I tried insted of `p = Profile.objects.get(user=u)`   =   `p = Profile.objects.get(Profile, id=1)`

But then it just showed the first Account on the Website.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ7Ox.jpg)

Views.py

```
    from blog.models import Post
from notification.models import Notification
from django.core.checks import messages
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Comment, Post
from .forms import CommentForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from users.models import Profile
from itertools import chain
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
import random

""" Home page with all posts """
def first(request):
    context = {
        'posts':Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/first.html', context)

""" Posts of following user profiles """
@login_required
def posts_of_following_profiles(request):


    profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
    users = [user for user in profile.following.all()]
    posts = []
    qs = None
    for u in users:
        p = Profile.objects.get(user=u)
        p_posts = p.user.post_set.all()
        posts.append(p_posts)
    my_posts = profile.profile_posts()
    posts.append(my_posts)
    if len(posts)>0:
        qs = sorted(chain(*posts), reverse=True, key=lambda obj:obj.date_posted)

    paginator = Paginator(qs, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
  
    return render(request,'blog/feeds.html',{'profile':profile,'posts':posts_list})


""" Post Like """
@login_required
def LikeView(request):

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
        notify = Notification.objects.filter(post=post, sender=request.user, notification_type=1)
        notify.delete()
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True
        notify = Notification(post=post, sender=request.user, user=post.author, notification_type=1)
        notify.save()

    context = {
        'post':post,
        'total_likes':post.total_likes(),
        'liked':liked,
    }

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blog/like_section.html',context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form':html})


""" Post save """
@login_required
def SaveView(request):

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    saved = False
    if post.saves.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.saves.remove(request.user)
        saved = False
    else:
        post.saves.add(request.user)
        saved = True
    
    context = {
        'post':post,
        'total_saves':post.total_saves(),
        'saved':saved,
    }

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blog/save_section.html',context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form':html})


""" Like post comments """
@login_required
def LikeCommentView(request): # , id1, id2              id1=post.pk id2=reply.pk
    post = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    cliked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        cliked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        cliked = True

    cpost = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('pid'))
    total_comments2 = cpost.comments.all().order_by('-id')
    total_comments = cpost.comments.all().filter(reply=None).order_by('-id')
    tcl={}
    for cmt in total_comments2:
        total_clikes = cmt.total_clikes()
        cliked = False
        if cmt.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            cliked = True

        tcl[cmt.id] = cliked


    context = {
        'comment_form':CommentForm(),
        'post':cpost,
        'comments':total_comments,
        'total_clikes':post.total_clikes(),
        'clikes':tcl
    }

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blog/comments.html',context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form':html})


""" Home page with all posts """
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html' 
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, *args,**kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data()
        users = list(User.objects.exclude(pk=self.request.user.pk))
        if len(users) > 3:
            cnt = 3
        else:
            cnt = len(users)
        random_users = random.sample(users, cnt)
        context['random_users'] = random_users
        return context


""" All the posts of the user """
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html' 
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')



""" Post detail view """
def PostDetailView(request,pk):

    stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)
    total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
    total_saves = stuff.total_saves()
    total_comments = stuff.comments.all().filter(reply=None).order_by('-id')
    total_comments2 = stuff.comments.all().order_by('-id')

    context = {}

    if request.method == "POST":
        comment_qs = None
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            form = request.POST.get('body')
            reply_id = request.POST.get('comment_id')
            if reply_id:
                comment_qs = Comment.objects.get(id=reply_id)
            
            comment = Comment.objects.create(name=request.user,post=stuff,body=form, reply=comment_qs)
            comment.save()
            if reply_id:
                notify = Notification(post=stuff, sender=request.user, user=stuff.author, text_preview=form, notification_type=4)
                notify.save()
            else:
                notify = Notification(post=stuff, sender=request.user, user=stuff.author, text_preview=form, notification_type=3)
                notify.save()
            total_comments = stuff.comments.all().filter(reply=None).order_by('-id')
            total_comments2 = stuff.comments.all().order_by('-id')
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
             

    tcl={}
    for cmt in total_comments2:
        total_clikes = cmt.total_clikes()
        cliked = False
        if cmt.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            cliked = True

        tcl[cmt.id] = cliked
    context["clikes"]=tcl


    liked = False
    if stuff.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        liked = True
    context["total_likes"]=total_likes
    context["liked"]=liked


    saved = False
    if stuff.saves.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        saved = True
    context["total_saves"]=total_saves
    context["saved"]=saved
    

    context['comment_form'] = comment_form

    context['post']=stuff
    context['comments']=total_comments

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blog/comments.html',context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form':html})

    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)


""" Create post """
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields =['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)



""" Update post """
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields =['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


""" Delete post """
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


""" Trends page """
def trends(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/trends.html', {'title':'Trends'})

    """ Settings page """
def settings(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/settings.html', {'title':'Settings'})

    """ Blog page """
def blog(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', {'title':'Blog'})




""" Search by post title or username """
def search(request):
    query = request.GET['query']
    if len(query) >= 150 or len(query) < 1:
        allposts = Post.objects.none()
    elif len(query.strip()) == 0:
        allposts = Post.objects.none()
    else:
        allpostsTitle = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
        allpostsAuthor = Post.objects.filter(author__username = query)
        allposts = allpostsAuthor.union(allpostsTitle)
    
    params = {'allposts': allposts}
    return render(request, 'blog/search_results.html', params)


""" Liked posts """
@login_required
def AllLikeView(request):
    user = request.user
    liked_posts = user.blogpost.all()
    context = {
        'liked_posts':liked_posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/liked_posts.html', context)


""" Saved posts """
@login_required
def AllSaveView(request):
    user = request.user
    saved_posts = user.blogsave.all()
    context = {
        'saved_posts':saved_posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/saved_posts.html', context)
```

The Error Message tells me the Problem is

> p = Profile.objects.get(user=u)

Settings.py

```
     """
    Django settings for myproject project.
    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.4.
    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/
    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
    """
    
    from pathlib import Path
    import os
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
    
    # Loading ENV
    env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
    load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
    
    # Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    
    
    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/
    
    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
    
    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG")
    
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] 
    
    # Application definition
    
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'crispy_forms',
        'django_cleanup',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'django.contrib.humanize',
        'ckeditor',
        'allauth',
        'allauth.account',
        'allauth.socialaccount',
        'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
        'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github',
        'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
        'users.apps.UsersConfig',
        'notification',
        'chat',
        'channels',
        'friend',
    ]
    
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]
    
    ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'
    
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'users/templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
    
    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
        'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    ]
    
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'
    
    
    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases
    
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }
    
    
    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
    
    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]
    
    
    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/
    
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
    
    TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
    
    USE_I18N = True
    
    USE_L10N = True
    
    USE_TZ = True
    
    
    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
    
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    
    CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
    
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
    LOGIN_URL = 'account_login'
    
    CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
        'default': {
            'width':'auto',
        },
    }
    
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_PORT = os.getenv("EMAIL_PORT")
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_USER')     # environment variable containing username
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_PASS')  # environment variable containing password
    
    GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY")
    
    MESSAGE_TAGS = {
            messages.DEBUG: 'alert-secondary',
            messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
            messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
            messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
            messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger',
    }
    
    ASGI_APPLICATION = "myproject.routing.application"
    
    CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
        "default":{
            "BACKEND":"channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
        },
    }
    
    SITE_ID = 2     # considering 2nd site in 'Sites' to be 127.0.0.1 (for dev)
    
    SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
        'google': {
            'SCOPE': [
                'profile',
                'email',
            ],
            'AUTH_PARAMS': {
                'access_type': 'online',
            }
        },
        'github': {
            'SCOPE': [
                'user',
                'repo',
                'read:org',
            ],
        }

}
```

Forms.py

```
 from django import forms
from django.forms import fields, widgets
from .models import Post, Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control custom-txt','cols':'40','rows':'3'}), label='')
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['body',]
```

There is a Link to the Error Message attached at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

It means the Profile object you are looking for does not exist in the database. You can handle the exception like so:

```py
try:
    Profile.objects.get(user=u)
except Profile.DoesNotExist:
    # do something here
```

Comment: This is the issue. You must have users that have profiles it seems. Or you can do Profile.objects.filter(user=u).exists():` for condition checks. Bottom line...you need to create a profile for each user either manually or in a post save for the model.

Comment: Hello, the answer didnt help me, when i paste that in the spot where the false code is, it doesnt accept it.